# Получить координату Y у овала зная позицию X

Tags: java, геометрия

Имеем овал:

```
a = width / 2; = 150
b = height / 2 = 50
```

Как найти точку пересечения X с Y зная значение X (как найти значения Y для синих точек?).

Зеленая точка наш X, зная Х мы должны получить точку Y чуть выше зеленой точки. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

up1:

Пробую так, но это работает неправильно:

```
    private RectF ovalView; // это мой овал
    ovalView = new RectF(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
    canvas.drawOval(ovalView, ovalPaint);
    //...
    float a = ovalView.width() / 2;
    float b = (ovalView.height() / 2);
    float[] y3 = getEllipseY(a, b, lastX);
    Log.d("vill", "\na:" + a + " b:" + b + " lasX:" + lastX + " y:" + y3[0]);

    drawThumb(canvas, lastX, y3[0]);


    private void drawThumb(Canvas canvas, float left, float top){
        Log.d("vill", "drawThumb top: " + top + " left: " + left);
        canvas.drawBitmap(thumb, left, top, thumbPaint);
    }
```

Comment: Для начала следует вывести математически зависимость Y от X, а программно там всё решается элементарно.

Comment: в уравнение эллипса подставьте координату Х, и получите два корня. возьмите ближайший, или какой вам там нужен. в чем проблема то?

Comment: Хосподя, на рисунке даже выражение написано, там корни отличаться будут только знаком.

Comment: Только не ясно, как размеры овала 150/50 соотносятся с этим уравнением ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перед нами эллипс. С его полуосями  `A` и `B`.

`A = 4`, `B = sqrt 7`, т.е. квадратный корень из 7.

Попробуем написать метод как найти `y` по известному `х`:

```
public static String getEllipseY (double A, double B, double x) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if (x > A || x < -A) throw new IllegalArgumentException(x + " is out of range" );
    double result = B * Math.sqrt(1 - x*x/(A*A));
    return String.format("y1=%f  y2=%f", result, -result);
}
```

и применим метод

```
System.out.println(getEllipseY(4.0, Math.sqrt(7), 3.0)); // y1=1,750000  y2=-1,750000
```

[Здесь все подробности.](http://mathprofi.ru/linii_vtorogo_poryadka_ellips_i_okruzhnost.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Да, что то такое я пробовал, значит у меня в корне не правильно. т.к. в моем случае нет ни каких отрицательных значений осей. Есть экранная форма, в которой рисуется овал(Canvas), и по клику (плоскость по Х)необходимо вычислить Y пересекающий нижнюю ось. Возможно вопрос нубский, но не могу разобраться..

Comment: В ответе решение как на рисунке, когда эллипс находится в центре координат. Любой другой вариант можно получить прибавлением постоянных к X и Y. Вычитайте у Х половину ширины экрана, а к Y прибавляйте, тогда эллипс будет как бы по центру. Размер полуосей задайте в пикселях.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю правильно все же вот так:

```
public static double getEllipseY(double x, int a, int b) {
    double a_a = Math.pow(a, 2), b_b = Math.pow(b, 2);
    double y = Math.sqrt((1 - (x * x) / a_a) * b_b);
    return y;
}
```

Проверить результат на правильность, вы можете тут: https://math.semestr.ru/line/ellipse.php (пункт "Построение графика эллипса"), и сразу будет понятно что код выше дает иной результат, отличающийся от представленного калькулятора.